# What is the benefit of 'break' in 'switch' statement (Dart Language)?

Tags: dart, switch-statement, break

When I write this code

```
void main() {
  var age = 18;

  switch(age){
    case 18:
      print("Age is 18");
    case 22:
      print("Age is 22");
    default:
      print("Default");
  }
}
```

It gives me this output
`Age is 18`
And when I add the `break` statement there is no difference and default block don't run in the two cases, **so what is exactly the benefit of break statement ?**

Comment: It was formerly required.  It's now optional as long as the case has at least one statement.  If the case has no statements, a break is necessary to prevent fall-through, although that's less useful now that you can use patterns with || operators.

Answer (score 9):

According to the Dart documentation, you do not need to use a break in a switch statement if all your case statements have a body. So for the below, a break statement will have no effect.

```
void main() {
  var age = 18;

  switch(age){
    case 18:
      print("Age is 18");
    case 22:
      print("Age is 22");
    default:
      print("Default");
  }
}
```

However if you had a case statement with an empty body and it did not have a break, it would fall through to the next that did have one (if any). So, for example, the below would print "Age is 22".

```
var age = 18;

switch(age){
  case 18:      
  case 22:
    print("Age is 22");
  default:
    print("Default");
}
```

Where as the following would print nothing.

```
var age = 18;

switch(age){
  case 18:
    break;
  case 22:
    print("Age is 22");
  default:
    print("Default");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `break` can be used anywhere in the switch case to break out of the switch.

It (or another control flow statement) used to be required at the end of switch cases, but that's no longer required. Now you only need to use `break` if you want to break *early*:

```dart
switch (something) {
  case int x: 
    if (x < 0) break;
    print("Non-negative integer");
  case String x:
    if (x.isEmpty) break;
    print("Non-empty string");
}
```

You can still put a `break` at the end, but it doesn't do anything that just reaching the end of a `case` wouldn't do anyway.